# How to add scrollbar and scale images?

Tags: java, swing, scroll, awt, scaling

Okay so basically I've been trying to make an interactive map using swing, awt, etc. I'm testing things out before heading straight into my project and I'm having difficulties with image size, and adding a scroll bar, the image is 2000x1000 png however it seems it only shows the middle 500x500 pixels in the center (I will provide images) also I've looked up some scrollbars however it doesn't seem to do anything? Help is appreciated basically I want the entire image to be viewable along with a scrollbar like in any other window. Here is my code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class GuiM extends JFrame{
    private JPanel map;
    private JPanel buttons;
    private JLabel imageLabel;
    public GuiM(){
        JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(map);  
        this.getContentPane().add(scroller, BorderLayout.EAST); 
        map = new JPanel();
        map.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        buttons = new JPanel();
        imageLabel =  new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("MapLI.png")));
        map.add(imageLabel);
        setLayout(new GridLayout());
        setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(true);
        add(map);
        add(buttons);
        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}

public class MainM {

    public static void main(String[] args){ 
        GuiM gui = new GuiM();
    }
}
```

Here are some images
This image is what i'd like to show up in my panel
[image: just a test map i'd like to use first]

However this is what I'm getting.
[image: problem]

Comment: Rather then using the Map panel, add the label to the scroll pane in its place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(map);
```

The above statement does nothing since the map variable is null. Get rid of it.

```
  this.getContentPane().add(scroller, BorderLayout.EAST);
```

The above statement does nothing because you later change the layout to a GridLayout and the scroller doesn't contain any components to display anyways. Get rid of it.

You want to add the scroller to the GUI, not the map so the code should be something like:

```
//add(map);
JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(map); // or add the "imageLabel"
add(scroller);
```

Or, it would be easier to just add the label to the scrollpane, there is no need to create a panel just to hold the label.

Also, the `setVisible(true)` statement should be moved to the bottom of the program, AFTER the components have been added to the frame and AFTER the pack().

Comment: This has worked thanks a lot, now my image takes up only from the center to the left side of the screen, is there a way to make it take up the full screen?

Comment: @Adamc23, you set the frame to use a GridLayout and added two components to the frame, so each gets 50% of the space. I would leave the default BorderLayout and then add the scrollPane to the `CENTER` and then add you buttonsPanel to the `SOUTH`. I suggest you read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more explanations and working examples. The example will also help you to better structure you code. Your code is wrong because you should NOT extend JFrame and you should build the GUI using SwingUtilities.invokeLater().

Comment: gotcha, I'll definitely look into this I wanted to add some buttons so I figured Grid would help out a little bit but as you mentioned I should definitely rethink this I'll give the layout managers a look over, once again thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You didnt add  label imagelabel to JScrollPane like below. pls add this to you code:

Modified code will look like this.

GuiM.java

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class GuiM extends JFrame{
    private JPanel map;
    private JPanel buttons;
    private JLabel imageLabel;
    public GuiM(){
        JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(map);  
        this.getContentPane().add(scroller, BorderLayout.EAST); 
        map = new JPanel();
        map.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        buttons = new JPanel();
        imageLabel =  new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("MapLI.png")));
        JScrollPane scrollpane=new JScrollPane(imageLabel);
        map.add(scrollpane);
        setLayout(new GridLayout());
        setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(true);
        add(map);
        add(buttons);
        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

and 
MainM.java

```
public class MainM {

    public static void main(String[] args){ 
        GuiM gui = new GuiM();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add scrollbars to your code using java.awt class. Please refer to the link for complete code.
http://www.fixoncloud.com/Home/LoginValidate/OneProblemComplete_Detailed.php?problemid=558